# PHP: how to generate variables from array foreach

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach

Is it possible to generate variable names from array or list to avoid repetition? 
I am pulling item values from html form, this is the excerpt of code:

```
    $item1 = $item2 = $item3 = $item4 = "";


    if (isset($_GET["submit"])) {

        if (!empty($_GET["item1"])) { $item1 = htmlentities($_GET["item1"]);} else { $item1="*"; }
        if (!empty($_GET["item2"])) { $item2 = htmlentities($_GET["item2"]);} else { $item2="*"; } 
        if (!empty($_GET["item3"])) { $item3 = htmlentities($_GET["item3"]);} else { $item3="*"; } 
        if (!empty($_GET["item4"])) { $item4 = htmlentities($_GET["item4"]);} else { $item4="*"; } 

    }
```

Would it be possible to make array of items  and generate the if block with foreach ?

Comment: Use arrays. Much easier to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider saving the values in an array

For the whole `$_GET`

```
$items = [];  
foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) {
    $items[$val] = !empty($val) ? htmlentities($val) : '*';
}

print_r($items);
```

For some predefined elements in `$elements`

```
$items = []; 
$elements = array('item1','item2');

foreach($elements as $val) {
    $items[$val] = !empty($_GET[$val]) ? htmlentities($_GET[$val]) : '*';
}

print_r($items);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

something like  this?

```
$names = array('item1', 'item2','item3','item4');

foreach($names as $name)
{
    $$name = '';
    if (isset($_GET['submit']))
        $$name = empty($_GET[$name])?'*':htmlentities($_GET[$name]);

}
```